# Running part of python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. I have a very basic question. Is there a way I can execute part of a python program?  ie some thing similar to Matlab where after running the code once, I can execute parts of the program

Comment: You can divide the program into functions and only use the functions you want

Comment: I would say it depends on your editor, and not on the language!
Ctrl+Alt+Enter on Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something similar to Matlab, check out [ipython](http://ipython.org/) - it comes with the goodness of python with a workflow similar to Matlab.

*ipython* has the concept of *Notebooks* which are composed of cells. These cells can be executed individually giving you the behavior you expect.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "cell" execution in MATLAB.

The [Spyder](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) python editor is in general a good approximation of MATLAB-style IDE for python. It supports executing the full script, the selected lines or a "cell" that is defined by a portion of code stating with a comment like

```
 # %%
```

or

```
 ###
```

To get Spyder I suggest to install a scientific python distribution such as Anaconda or WinPython.

Alternatively, as pointed out by vikramls, you can embrace a more modern paradigm, convert your script to an ipython notebook and get "cell" execution for free.

**PS** The ipython notebook is a fantastic environment that allow to mix rich text, code and plots in a single document that is great for some workflows. On the other hand Spyder provides some unique features such as graphical variable inspector (a-la MATLAB), integrated HTML documentation and code error analysis not available in the notebook.